# How to find XML element fast using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, parsing

I am quite new to XML and to what makes code effective, and the code I am using takes quite a long time to run.

So I want to extract the elevation from given lat, long-values as fast as possible (I have a lot of lat,long-points). This is how I tried it:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib.request import urlopen
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def elevation(lat, long):
    query = ('http://openwps.statkart.no/skwms1/wps.elevation2?request=Execute&service=WPS&version=1.0.0'
                 f'&identifier=elevation&datainputs=lat={lat};lon={long};epsg=4326')
    parsing = "{http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0}"
    with urlopen(query) as f:
        tree = ET.parse(f)
        root = tree.getroot()
        return float(root.findall(f".//{parsing}Data/*")[0].text)
```

Using this function on the data set I have extracted from an csv-file, with several datasets within the same file separated by a "new_sheep"-line:

```
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/ninsalv/Documents/Sheepdata/Data.csv", delimiter=';',
                 dtype={"Initial start": "str", "Start": "str", "Stop": "str"})
print(df.head())

dataset = 1
Lat = []
Long = []
temp = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if "new_sheep" in df.iloc[i][0]:
        temp += 1
        continue
    if temp == dataset:
        Lat.append(df.iloc[i][3])
        Long.append(df.iloc[i][4])
    if temp > dataset:
        break

step = np.linspace(0,len(Lat),len(Lat))
altitude = []
for i in range(len(Lat)):
    altitude.append(elevation(Lat[i], Long[i]))
    if (i % 100) == 0:
        print("round number ", i)
plt.plot(step, altitude)
```

This works, but it takes almost a minute to find every 100 altitudes, and I have about 7000-15000 points to check in my dataset. Does anybody know either XML, pandas or something else that may make my code faster?

Comment: I'd guess that the problem isn't the XML parsing but the fact that you're making several thousand HTTP calls to a remote webservice.  The webservice endpoint you're using appears to return an elevation for only a single point: is there an endpoint that you can pass multiple points to?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to get data (HTTP request) you are looking for in **parallel**. You cab use multi threading for that.

See the example below.

```
import requests
from requests.sessions import Session
import time
from threading import Thread,local
from queue import Queue

url_list = [] # TODO long list of urls to be populated by your code
q = Queue(maxsize=0)            #Use a queue to store all URLs
for url in url_list:
    q.put(url)
thread_local = local()          #The thread_local will hold a Session object

def get_session() -> Session:
    if not hasattr(thread_local,'session'):
        thread_local.session = requests.Session() # Create a new Session if not exists
    return thread_local.session

def download_link() -> None:
    '''download link worker, get URL from queue until no url left in the queue'''
    session = get_session()
    while not q.empty():
        url = q.get()
        with session.get(url) as response:
            print(f'Read {len(response.content)} from {url}')
        q.task_done()          # tell the queue, this url downloading work is done

def download_all(urls) -> None:
    '''Start 10 threads, each thread as a wrapper of downloader'''
    thread_num = 10
    for i in range(thread_num):
        t_worker = Thread(target=download_link)
        t_worker.start()
    q.join()                   # main thread wait until all url finished downloading

print("start work")
start = time.time()
download_all(url_list)
end = time.time()
print(f'download {len(url_list)} links in {end - start} seconds')
```

Comment: Better to not print anything from thread but return result and process all output in main thread. And I can't find any exit from infinity loop in `download_link()`. Seems like you tell the queue that downloading finished but thread keep working in background till the end of script execution. It could create problems, better to omit this loop at all or add some condition.

Comment: The code I have posted is not "cut & paste" code. Its more like a concept that I think OP should adopt.